# Radiation pressure and photon momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, photons, photoelectric-effect

From classical electromagnetism we know that the electromagnetic field carries momentum, which is related to energy density of the field and in particular can be transferred to a particle via interaction. On the other side we also know from the photoelectric effect that $E=hv\nu$ and a photon  has momentum $p$

What is the relation between the two point of view?

Comment: For a photon the mass is zero so we get $E=cp=h\nu$. As $c=\nu \lambda$ this means that   $p=h/\lambda$ for the photon momentum. Is this what you are asking?